# How to access json sub-objects from Android to PHP?

Tags: php, android, json

I have this structure in Android:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        mjson.put("receiveOrderId", receiveOrderId);
        mjson.put("packageId", packageId);
        mjson.put("partNumber", partNumber);
        mjson.put("qty", qty);
        mjson.put("serial", serial);
        mjson.put("locationId", locationId);

        json.put("version", "6");
        json.put("token", token);
        json.put("data", mjson);

        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);
```

And I need to decode in php, how I can access the values ​​of "partNumber" or "qty"?

try it this way, but it did not work:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
$version = $json->{'version'};
$token = $json->{'token'};
$receiveOrderId = $json->{'receiveOrderId'};
$packageId = $json->{'packageId'};
$partNumber = $json->{'partNumber'};
$qty = $json->{'qty'};
$serial = $json->{'serial'};
$locationId = $json->{'locationId'};
```

**Sorry for my bad english, im from Mexico.*

Comment: Have you tried printing out `$data` or `$json` to make sure it has all the data you sent?

Comment: Yes,i printed $data and the info is ok! but i cant access to individual elements

Answer (score 0):

can you print your $json?

```
var_dump($json);
```

it must look like:

```
'{"qty": 123, "version": "xxxxx"}';
```

make sure the index names (qty, version, ...) are embraced by double quote, not single quote

Comment: They have single quote, why is that?